# How to return php array from mysql into google geolocation

Tags: php, javascript, html, google-maps, geolocation

I have data in mysql database and I want to be able to read that data in php array and use it for google geolocation.

So for this example I want to use only `SELECT *` statement, as I will not be bothering you with some parameters...

What I want to achieve is to get marked line from point A to point B ( depending where GPS location was saved )

This is the link what I want to have on my map: [POLYLINE](https://google-developers.appspot.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/polyline-simple) in this example there are only 4 data in the array I want to have it more.

So now we can get back to the code. This is my PHP script for connecting to mysql. I have been using mysqli as I will have stored procedures later one in the database, so don't get confused.

```
class dbMySql 
{
static function Exec($query) {
// open database
$conn = mysqli_connect(
$GLOBALS['cfg_db_Server'],
$GLOBALS['cfg_db_User'],
$GLOBALS['cfg_db_Pass']
);
if($conn === false) 
{
    throw new Exception(mysqli_connect_error());
}
mysqli_select_db($conn,$GLOBALS['cfg_db_Name']);
$result = mysqli_query($conn,$query);
if(is_bool($result) && !$result) 
{
    $error = mysqli_error($conn);
    mysqli_close($conn);
    throw new Exception($error);
}
mysqli_close($conn);
return $result;
}
}
```

How to connect this php script to code that is example on google API page, and insert my array values when button is clicked instead of the fixed ones:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no" />
    <script type="text/javascript"
      src="http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=KEY&sensor=true">
    </script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
  function initialize() {
  var myLatLng = new google.maps.LatLng(0, -180);
  var myOptions = {
    zoom: 3,
    center: myLatLng,
    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.TERRAIN
  };

  var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"),
      myOptions);
  var flightPlanCoordinates = [
    new google.maps.LatLng(37.772323, -122.214897),
    new google.maps.LatLng(21.291982, -157.821856),
    new google.maps.LatLng(-18.142599, 178.431),
    new google.maps.LatLng(-27.46758, 153.027892)
  ];
  var flightPath = new google.maps.Polyline({
    path: flightPlanCoordinates,
    strokeColor: "#FF0000",
    strokeOpacity: 1.0,
    strokeWeight: 2
  });

  flightPath.setMap(map);
}
    </script>
  </head>
  <body onload="initialize()">
    <div id="map_canvas" style="width:100%; height:80%"></div>
    <div><button type="button">Click Me!</button></div>
  </body>
</html>
```

EDIT:

this is what I get when I do your code:
[image: error]

EDIT2:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no" />
    <style type="text/css">
      html { height: 100% }
      body { height: 100%; margin: 0; padding: 0 }
      #map_canvas { height: 100% }
    </style>
    <script type="text/javascript"
      src="http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=key&sensor=true">
    </script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
  function initialize() {
  var myLatLng = new google.maps.LatLng(0, 180);
  var myOptions = {
    zoom: 3,
    center: myLatLng,
    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.TERRAIN
  };

  var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"),
      myOptions);
  var flightPlanCoordinates = [ <?php echo implode(',', $coordinates) ?> ];
  ];
  var flightPath = new google.maps.Polyline({
    path: flightPlanCoordinates,
    strokeColor: "#FF0000",
    strokeOpacity: 1.0,
    strokeWeight: 2
  });

  flightPath.setMap(map);
}
</script>
</script>
    <?PHP
class dbMySql {

    static function Exec($query) {
        // open database
        $conn = mysqli_connect('localhost','root','*****');
        if($conn === false) {
            throw new Exception(mysqli_connect_error());
    }
        mysqli_select_db($conn,'data_gps');

    $result = mysqli_query($conn,$query);

        if(is_bool($result) && !$result) {
            $error = mysqli_error($conn);
            mysqli_close($conn);
            throw new Exception($error);
        }

        mysqli_close($conn);

    return $result;
    }
}
$coordinates  = array();
$result = dbMySql::Exec('SELECT lat,lng FROM data');
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result))
   $coordinates[] = 'new google.maps.LatLng(' . $row['lat'] . ', ' . $row['lng'] . ')' ;
 ?>
    </script>
  </head>
  <body onload="initialize()">
    <div id="map_canvas" style="width:100%; height:80%"></div>
    <div><button type="button">Click Me!</button></div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Im guessing that you need to iterate between the results and then echo them into the javascript.

Im assuming you have the lat and lng stored in your database.

```
$coordinates  = array();
$result = dbMySql::Exec('SELECT lat, lng FROM table WHERE id = 1');
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result))
    $coordinates[] = 'new google.maps.LatLng(' . $row['lat'] . ', ' . $row['lng'] . ')';
```

And then on your javascript section

```
var flightPlanCoordinates = [ <?php echo implode(',', $coordinates) ?> ];
```

Edit:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<?PHP
class dbMySql {

    static function Exec($query) {
        // open database
        $conn = mysqli_connect('localhost','root','*****');
        if($conn === false) {
            throw new Exception(mysqli_connect_error());
    }
        mysqli_select_db($conn,'data_gps');

    $result = mysqli_query($conn,$query);

        if(is_bool($result) && !$result) {
            $error = mysqli_error($conn);
            mysqli_close($conn);
            throw new Exception($error);
        }

        //mysqli_close($conn);

    return $result;
    }
}
$coordinates  = array();
$result = dbMySql::Exec('SELECT lat,lng FROM data');
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result))
   $coordinates[] = 'new google.maps.LatLng(' . $row['lat'] . ', ' . $row['lng'] . ')';
 ?>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no" />
    <style type="text/css">
      html { height: 100% }
      body { height: 100%; margin: 0; padding: 0 }
      #map_canvas { height: 100% }
    </style>
    <script type="text/javascript"
      src="http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=key&sensor=true">
    </script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
  function initialize() {
  var myLatLng = new google.maps.LatLng(0, 180);
  var myOptions = {
    zoom: 3,
    center: myLatLng,
    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.TERRAIN
  };

  var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"),
      myOptions);
  var flightPlanCoordinates = [<?php echo implode(',', $coordinates) ?>];
  var flightPath = new google.maps.Polyline({
    path: flightPlanCoordinates,
    strokeColor: "#FF0000",
    strokeOpacity: 1.0,
    strokeWeight: 2
  });

  flightPath.setMap(map);
}
</script>
  </head>
  <body onload="initialize()">
    <div id="map_canvas" style="width:100%; height:80%"></div>
    <div><button type="button">Click Me!</button></div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: hi, I have tried your code. When I perform echo coordinates I am really getting the results of longitude and latitude. But when I put it in my code it doesn't work. Map is not loading, I have put the php inside the script

Comment: Does your file end in '.php'?

Comment: Hey men I need your help. Check this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10931109/how-to-load-and-array-of-the-points-with-id-from-php-to-google-and-set-markers